# If variables are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

> Given $X, Y$ are random variables with distribution:
>   $$P(X=m, Y=n) =  \frac{2 \times 3^{(m-n)}}{e^3 \times m!}$$
>   check if these variables are independent.

Could anyone give me any suggestions how to check this? I know that I should check every combination of $m$ and $n$ but how to handle with left side of equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that $n$ is an integer $\geq 1$ and $m$ is an integer $\geq 0$, otherwise $P(X=m, Y=n)$ isn't a distribution.

Firstly, we can calculate the marginal distributions:

$$P(X=m) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} P(X=m, Y=n) =  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{2 \cdot 3^{(m-n)}}{e^3 \cdot m!} = \\
=  \frac{2 \cdot 3^{m}}{e^3 \cdot m!}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} 3^{-n} =  \frac{2 \cdot 3^{m}}{e^3 \cdot m!}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{3^{m}}{e^3 \cdot m!},$$

since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} 3^{-n} = \frac{1}{2}$ (it is a geometric series, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a^{-n} = \frac{1}{a-1}, a > 1$).

Moreover:

$$P(Y=n) = \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} P(X=m, Y=n) =  \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \frac{2 \cdot 3^{(m-n)}}{e^3 \cdot m!} = \\
=\frac{2 \cdot 3^{-n}}{e^3}\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \frac{3^{m}}{ m!} = \frac{2 \cdot 3^{-n}}{e^3}e^3= 2 \cdot 3^{-n}$$

since $\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \frac{3^{m}}{ m!} = e^3$ (the Taylor sum of $e^x$ is $\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{m}}{ m!}$).

It is well-known that:

> $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables if and only if $$P(X=m,
> Y=n) = P(X=m)P(Y=n)$$

You can easily check by yourself that in your case $P(X=m,Y=n) = P(X=m)P(Y=n)$, and hence $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The state space is not rectangular; since, it is not rectangular you may be able to infer about the probability of Y when X is given, which makes it dependent.

Why is the state space not rectangular?

**Hint:** Find the possible values of **n** for different fixed values of **m** (remember probability values should be between 0 and 1, both inclusive).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying "not rectangular".

Comment: @JeanMarie, if you plot all the possible values of **n** for each value of **m**, then the graph is not a rectangle (note: there are no restrictions on **n** and **m**).

Answer (score 0):

I think that a shorter path can be taken without computation (or so few...) , by splitting, right at the beginning, the joint distribution into a product of two probability distributions, one  depending on $m$ only , the other depending on $n$ only.

$$P(X=m, Y=n) =  \frac{e^{-3}3^{m}}{m!}\times 2\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^n$$

which is the "tensorial" product of two (well known) probability distributions, a Poisson($\lambda=3$) and a Geometric($p=1/3$).

We are in a case of independance by construction...